# Отправка на сервер массива байтов

Tags: java

У меня есть метод, который отправляет на сервер данные:

```
public void setFloor(String floor) throws IOException {
    byte[] array = floor.getBytes();
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/level");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
        bos.write(array, 0, array.length);
    }
}
```

Но все они приходят со знаком "=", то есть при дебагге в массиве байт только один символ, отправляю "6", но на сервер приходит уже "6=" и тд. Как мне это исправить?

Вот код чтения данных на сервере:

```
@PostMapping()
    public String postEndPoint(@RequestBody String floor) {
        return elevatorService.setFloor(Integer.valueOf(floor));
    }
```

Вообще, у меня приходят только числовые значения, но тип Integer вообще не доходит, а String приходит с =

Comment: Как вы читаете данные на сервере?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ передачи байтов по HTTP, это преобразование этих байтов в Base64 и передачи их как обычный текст. На стороне клиента Вы, при помощи Base64 кодируете массив байтов и отправляете в теле запроса как текст. На сторне сервера, Вы принимаете String и декодируете его обратно в массив байтов.

Comment: мне по сути не обязательно передавать байты, мне нужно передать целочисленное значение.но я попробую, спасибо!